# How is the result stored in jQuery Ajax data object on success callback

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery Ajax to send request and get response on success/failure.

**Server Side**

I'm using POST to send request to another script that fetches the query results from MySQL array using `mysql_fetch_array($query)`. When I echo this results, I get to display the string object data.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT name from builder";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
   echo $result["name"];           
}
```

**Client Side**

```
success:function(data)
{
echo data;
}
```

In the client side, when I try to get the results I use data in success which is a string object in success callback.
How does the object get stored in data object
I have the following doubts

1. When I fetch array results and echo it from PHP script, how is it copied to data object in success call back.
2. How can I seperate this result data object to form JSON string.

**Addendum**
When I fetch query results, I see all values are copied and cannot be separated with split function. How can I split this values.

Comment: `echo data;` in success callback, this is not the way to render/store data in js.

Comment: @Jai echo data gives me this - "A""B""C""D""E""F ""G"

Comment: are you sure at client side in js you can use php method that way.

Answer (score 0):

use the php internal function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Hi @sebastian, should I echo a json_encoded string from backend for this?

Comment: yeah, you should, else you have to parse your return in js.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can emit json using **`json_encode`** .
In jQuery's success function you can parse json and use as

```
success:function(data)
{
//echo data;
var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
// use it by index numbers as

var first_element = parsedData[0];
// ans so on..
}
```